# Custom module "was not found" on import - VueJS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I've created a custom component called `RegisterPayMonthlyDialog.vue` on my source tree. The problem is that when it is imported on the view `Monthly.vue` the npm can't find the module.

**error**

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                         11:06:29 PM

This dependency was not found:

* @/components/dialogs/RegisterPayMonthlyDialog in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./nod
e_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--18-0!./node_modules/cache-load
er/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Monthly.vue?vue&type
=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/components/dialogs/RegisterPayMonthlyDialog
```

**source tree**

[image]

**Monthly.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container class="pa-5">
    <h3>Mensalidades</h3>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import RegisterPayMonthlyDialog from "@/components/dialogs/RegisterPayMonthlyDialog"; // can't find it

export default {
  name: "Monthly",
  components: {
    RegisterPayMonthlyDialog
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showPayMonthyDialog: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**RegisterPayMonthlyDialog.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-dialog v-model="show" width="500">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title primary-title class="title">Pagamento de mensalidade</v-card-title>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>s

<script>
export default {
  name: "RegisterPayMonthlyDialog",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: {
    show: Boolean
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: In addition to the typo you have an extra `s` after the `template` closing tag in your `RegisterPayMonthlyDialog.vue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo error. see code below

Your are importing this file named `RegisterPayMonthlyDialog`, but  your file was named as `RegisterPayMonhtlyDialog`,

To solve it, change your file name to `RegisterPayMonthlyDialog.vue`

and import it like this

```
import RegisterPayMonthlyDialog from "@/components/dialogs/RegisterPayMonthlyDialog"
```